# ParseServer bad value in mongoObjectToParseObject when query order by Date descending

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I use a self host ParseServer and my database currently grows more than 80k objects in a collection. I use parse-dashboard to view and manage them. The problem happens today when I browse that collection sorted by "publishedDate" field descending. The error is below:

`ParseError { code: 1, message: 'bad value in mongoObjectToParseObject' }`

It only happens with that field ordered by descending, works well by ascending. Other fields in that collection work well too. I've checked on my mobile apps, the data cannot be loaded because of that error.

I've tried many ways:

(1) set all null values to a Date value;

(2) copied all that field's values to a new field and copied them back;

(3) converted that field's date values to Number and stored in other field and converted them back (using mongo language)

```
object.time = object.publishedDate.getTime(); //or
object.publishedDate = new ISODate(object.time); // this works but the value is wrong (for example Jan 31, 9998 while expected is Sep 3, 2001)
object.publishedDate = new ISODate(new Date(object.time).toISOString()) //or
object.publishedDate = new Date(object.time);
```

None of them help to solve the error.
My local database work well with the same data.

Anyone has ever faced this error? Please help!
All advices are welcome. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

mongo db version: v3.0.8

parseserver version: v2.8.1

Comment: this is perhaps a bug with the server itself. Can you perhaps open an issue on the repository?

Comment: Thanks @flovilmart. I have opened a new issue on the repo.